# How to transform a key/value string into separate columns?

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns, key-value

I've got a `data.frame` with `key/value string` column containing information about features and their values for a set of users. Something like this:

```
data<-data.frame(id=1:3,statid=c("s003e","s093u","s085t"),str=c("a:1,7:2","a:1,c:4","a:3,b:5,c:33"))
data
#   id statid          str
# 1  1  s003e      a:1,7:2
# 2  2  s093u      a:1,c:4
# 3  3  s085t a:3,b:5,c:33
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a data.frame containing column for every feature. Like this:

```
data_after<-data.frame(id=1:3,statid=c("s003e","s093u","s085t"),
                   a=c(1,1,3),b=c(0,0,5),c=c(0,4,33),"7"=c(2,0,0))
data_after
#   id statid a b  c X7
# 1  1  s003e 1 0  0  2
# 2  2  s093u 1 0  4  0
# 3  3  s085t 3 5 33  0
```

I was trying to use `str_split` from `stringr` package and then transform elements of created list to `data.frames` (later bind them using for example `rbind.fill` from `plyr`) but couldn't done it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See `splitstackshape` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
data %>% mutate(str = strsplit(str, ",")) %>% unnest(str) %>% 
         separate(str, into = c('var', 'val'), sep = ":") %>% spread(var, val, fill = 0)

#   id statid 7 a b  c
# 1  1  s003e 2 1 0  0
# 2  2  s093u 0 1 0  4
# 3  3  s085t 0 3 5 33
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cSplit` to do this in a cleaner way.  Convert the data to 'long' format by splitting at `,`, then do the split at `:` and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
dcast(cSplit(cSplit(data, "str", ",", "long"), "str", ":"), 
                    id+statid~str_1, value.var="str_2", fill = 0)
#   id statid 7 a b  c
#1:  1  s003e 2 1 0  0
#2:  2  s093u 0 1 0  4
#3:  3  s085t 0 3 5 33
```